# PSR-4 funciona localmente pero en línea no encuentra ni una sóla clase

Tags: php7

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde implemento PSR-4 desde **composer**, donde tengo esto:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Lib\\": "lib"
    }
},
```

Luego tengo un archivo donde declaro un espacio de nombre y la clase respectiva:

```
namespace Lib\Models;

class Gato{....}
```

Y finallmente tengo un lugar donde procuro cargar el modelo "Gato"

```
use Lib\Models\Gato;
$gatoSalvaje = new Gato();
```

Entonces el asunto es que localmente me funciona perfectamente pero en producción en la WEB no me funciona para nada .. 
Tanto en línea como local tengo la misma versión de PHP y no entiendo porque el sistema me devuelve que no encuentra la clase "Gato" en cambio localmente todo va de maravillas pero en producción nada .. para escribir el código uso PHP Storm y este me cachea perfectamente el método y no da errores en el debug ...
Debo mencionar que no estoy trabajando con Laravel .. sino con PHP nativo y algunas dependencias que manejo con **composer** como por ejemplo **eloquent** para estionar todos los modelos de datos, uso XAMPP (con php 7.3.14)
Que me puedo estar perdiendo .. ?

Comment: Ya revisaste el log de errores a ver si se grabó algo?

Comment: no entiendo como puede funcionarte... si tu namespace es `Lib\Models\Gato;`, entonces tu clase deberia usada como  `use Lib\Models\Gato\Gato;`...

Comment: Ciertamente fue mi error al escribir la pregunta ... el "namespace" realmente es "Lib\Model", es así como está y localmente funciona pero no en producción .. el error resultante en el log queda así: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Lib\Models\Gato' not found

Comment: Hciste require del archivo autoload.php en el archivo donde importas el namespace de la clase Gato?

Comment: No comprendo bien  uso composer y en el archivo composer.json donde ingreso los datos PSR-4 también tengo otras 8 dependencias de librerías externas y todas las carga composer automáticamente con un "require vendor/autoload.php" que hago al inicio de la respuesta, estas dependencias se cargan y funcionan perfectamente, pero no se es si tengo que añadir un "require vendor/autoload.php" en cada llamada al namespace (use Lib\Models\Gato) y sobre todo insisto que localmente me funciona perfectamente .. es en producción en un servidor de Internet donde da el error de no encontrar las clases

Answer (score 0):

> Todos los nombres de las clases DEBEN ser referenciados en una forma
>   que tenga en cuenta las mayúsculas y minúsculas.

[Especificación PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#2-specification)

Es decir, los *Namespaces* y los nombres de las clases (*ClassName*) son "*Sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas*" (case-sensitivity).

Este sería un ejemplo en tu caso:

```
Lib
  |- Models
      | - Gato.php
```

Otros ejemplos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]